# Using django-stripe's built-in webhook support

Tags: python, django, webhooks, stripe-payments

I'm using Django 3.0, dj-stripe 2.0, and the Stripe CLI. [dj-stripe](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/stable-2.0/index.html) provides native support for Stripe webhooks, and their documentation says to include the following in my django project's main `urls.py` file to expose the webhook endpoint:

`url(r"^stripe/", include("djstripe.urls", namespace="djstripe")),`

I have done this, but how do I now leverage the endpoint?

As a separate experiment, I created a `payments` app, setup the URL conf, and successfully called the view when triggering the non dj-stripe webhook endpoint via the Stripe CLI. But it doesn't use any `dj-stripe` functionality:

```
# project urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('stripe/', include("djstripe.urls", namespace="djstripe")),
    path('payments/', include("payments.urls", namespace="payments")),
]
```

```
# payments/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name="payments"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.my_handler, name="my-handler"),
]
```

```
# payments/views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_handler(request, **kwargs):
    print(request.body)
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Running `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/payments/` and, in a separate window, `stripe trigger product.created` returns a `200` response.

But `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/stripe/webhook/` and `stripe trigger product.created` returns a `500`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[UPDATE]

I have not modified the default `DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_URL` or `DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_VALIDATION` settings. In `settings.py` I have:

```
STRIPE_LIVE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_LIVE_PUBLIC_KEY")
STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY")
STRIPE_TEST_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_TEST_PUBLIC_KEY")
STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY")
STRIPE_LIVE_MODE = os.environ.get("STRIPE_LIVE_MODE")
DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET = "*************************************"
```

The test keys are pulled from `env/bin/activate`:

```
export STRIPE_LIVE_PUBLIC_KEY="pk_live_****...."
export STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY="sk_live_****...."
export STRIPE_TEST_PUBLIC_KEY="pk_test_****...."
export STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY="sk_test_****...."
export STRIPE_LIVE_MODE="False"
```

When I run `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/stripe/webhook/` and trigger `stripe trigger customer.created` I get the following 500 error:

```
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_NTtzsTFS8uVdfL: No such customer; a similar object exists in test mode, but a live mode key was used to make this request.
```

But I don't understand how my keys could be getting mixed up, because the webhooks work fine when I trigger the same event and listen via the `/payments/` endpoint.

Thank you again for your time.

Comment: What happens when you run: python manage.py djstripe_sync_models . I think you just need to add the stripe api keys from the django-admin

Answer (score 3):

In summary, you need to decorate a handler function using the `@webhooks.handler` decorator.

You have some examples in the [webhooks section](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/webhooks/) of the dj-stripe documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Pablo. Following the documentation, I imported the decorator and apply it to my handler function, but I get a 403 because it's looking for the csrf_token. Adding the csrf_exempt decorator makes it work again, but how do I know  that webhbooks.handler is making that happen?

Comment: Also, the handler is called even when the webhook I trigger is for a different object. It still gets called when I run `stripe trigger product.created` even though the decorator specifies "customer", which makes me think the decorator isn't having any effect.

Comment: Are you using the default values for `DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_URL` and `DJSTRIPE_WEBHOOK_VALIDATION` or have you modified them?

You don't need csrf_exempt because the [ProcessWebhookView](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/blob/master/djstripe/views.py#L17) view already does it for you.

Also, `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/stripe/webhook/` is the correct stripe command you have to run.

Comment: I have not modified either of those default values, no. I've added more information in the original question to explain what's happening now. Thanks again for your time, @Pablo Castellano.

Comment: @NathanMagyar Do you happen to have `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` set as well?